# How to make Result Scan Barcode matching with the Data Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, barcode-scanner

I just want to develop an application that can scan barcode and I also just learned to develop the application. Well the problem dan i'm confusing is, how do the results of the scan barcode send data and match the data then appear like "User Registered".

I use the library from ZXING and RETROFIT,

here is my coding:

```
public class ScanQRCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qrcode);

    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}



   @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawresult) {
 if (rawresult == postData()) {
   // i must write what?
    }
        Log.v("TAG", rawresult.getText());
        Log.v("TAG", rawresult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Hasil Scan");
        builder.setMessage(rawresult.getText());
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();

        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
```

And my model had 2 like this:

```
public class DataRegisteredIn {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private RegisteredIn data;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public RegisteredIn getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(RegisteredIn data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

and this :

```
public class RegisteredIn {
    @SerializedName("participants_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer participantsId;
    @SerializedName("registration_number")
    @Expose
    private String registrationNumber;
    @SerializedName("title_name")
    @Expose
    private String titleName;
    @SerializedName("call_badge_name")
    @Expose
    private String callBadgeName;
    @SerializedName("family_name")
    @Expose
    private String familyName;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_title")
    @Expose
    private String lastTitle;
    @SerializedName("event_meals_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer eventMealsId;
    @SerializedName("place")
    @Expose
    private String place;
    @SerializedName("item_name")
    @Expose
    private String itemName;

    public Integer getParticipantsId() {
        return participantsId;
    }

    public void setParticipantsId(Integer participantsId) {
        this.participantsId = participantsId;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    public String getTitleName() {
        return titleName;
    }

    public void setTitleName(String titleName) {
        this.titleName = titleName;
    }

    public String getCallBadgeName() {
        return callBadgeName;
    }

    public void setCallBadgeName(String callBadgeName) {
        this.callBadgeName = callBadgeName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastTitle() {
        return lastTitle;
    }

    public void setLastTitle(String lastTitle) {
        this.lastTitle = lastTitle;
    }

    public Integer getEventMealsId() {
        return eventMealsId;
    }

    public void setEventMealsId(Integer eventMealsId) {
        this.eventMealsId = eventMealsId;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

This is also the first time I ask, so for example there is something I need to add let me clear, please tell me clearly because honestly I am very beginner.

thank you

**Updated**
this is a little picture what I want to make, in the picture to the left it is my application that can only get the value of the barcode but like the picture is the right one that I want, so like the value of the barcode is translated into a shape like the picture in right.

[image: What i want]

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you need to do and what is the problem your facing?

Comment: I had the put image, please check again thankyou

Comment: Tell me if i got this correct. You are geeting a number from your scan result and then want to check if this number is registered using an API? And for making the API call, you want to use retrofit?

Comment: That's right, and the API using POST method

Comment: What have you tried for retrofit?

Comment: Some data i GET, and i just confusing how can i put the retrofit code for the make it work.